# Shell script to filter IP addresses from logfile

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, scripting, logs, ip

We've got a regular socket dump that we've asked a customer to run, and I was just wondering if the community had any thoughts on identifying multiple connected addresses in a net stat socket list.

```
Active Internet connections (including servers)
PCB      Proto Recv-Q Send-Q  Local Address      Foreign Address    (state)
-------- ----- ------ ------  ------------------ ------------------ -------
18970e0  TCP        0      0  10.51.57.214.1028     10.51.57.211.20021    ESTABLISHED
1897374  TCP        0      0  10.51.57.214.23       10.51.102.86.58998    ESTABLISHED
18960e4  TCP        0      0  10.51.57.214.1028     10.51.102.48.59466    ESTABLISHED
189747c  TCP        0      0  10.51.57.214.1031     10.51.82.22.63682     ESTABLISHED
18972f0  TCP        0      0  10.51.57.214.1028     10.51.101.72.64318    ESTABLISHED
18969a8  TCP        0      0  10.51.57.214.1028     10.51.102.75.61478    ESTABLISHED
1896e4c  TCP        0      0  10.51.57.214.1028     10.51.102.74.52111    ESTABLISHED
1896924  TCP        0      0  10.51.57.214.1028     10.51.57.232.57303    ESTABLISHED
1896d44  TCP        0      0  10.51.57.214.1028     10.51.57.232.57302    ESTABLISHED
1896ed0  TCP        0      0  10.51.57.214.1028     10.51.57.202.49952    ESTABLISHED
1896cc0  TCP        0      0  10.51.57.214.1028     10.51.57.242.56605    ESTABLISHED
1896b34  TCP        0      0  10.51.57.214.1028     10.51.57.245.49418    ESTABLISHED
1895b38  TCP        0      0  10.51.57.214.1028     10.51.57.245.49402    ESTABLISHED
18958a4  TCP        0      0  10.51.57.214.1028     10.51.57.244.49390    ESTABLISHED
18968a0  TCP        0      0  10.51.57.214.1028     10.51.101.36.60993    ESTABLISHED
1896714  TCP        0      0  10.51.57.214.1028     10.51.82.22.53412     ESTABLISHED
1896ab0  TCP        0      0  10.51.57.214.1028     10.51.57.243.50377    ESTABLISHED
1895ed4  TCP        0      0  10.51.57.214.1113     10.51.57.203.62953    ESTABLISHED
1896a2c  TCP        0     25  10.51.57.214.1028     10.51.57.243.50362    ESTABLISHED
1895bbc  TCP        0      0  10.51.57.214.1028     10.51.57.196.49313    ESTABLISHED
189681c  TCP        0      0  10.51.57.214.1028     10.51.57.101.52556    ESTABLISHED
1896798  TCP        0      0  10.51.57.214.1028     10.51.57.201.53746    ESTABLISHED
1896c3c  TCP        0      0  10.51.57.214.1028     10.51.57.193.51058    ESTABLISHED
1896588  TCP        0      0  10.51.57.214.1028     10.51.57.195.49358    ESTABLISHED
18962f4  TCP        0      0  10.51.57.214.1028     10.51.101.92.59060    ESTABLISHED
1896504  TCP        0      0  10.51.57.214.1028     10.51.57.213.62754    ESTABLISHED
18963fc  TCP        0      0  10.51.57.214.1028     10.51.57.213.62753    ESTABLISHED
1896690  TCP        0      0  10.51.57.214.1052     10.51.57.203.62953    ESTABLISHED
189660c  TCP        0      0  10.51.57.214.1028     10.51.57.241.54348    ESTABLISHED
1896168  TCP        0      0  10.51.57.214.1047     10.51.57.203.62953    ESTABLISHED
1896378  TCP        0      0  10.51.57.214.1031     10.51.57.203.62961    ESTABLISHED
1895f58  TCP        0      0  10.51.57.214.1028     10.51.57.203.62958    ESTABLISHED
1896270  TCP        0      0  10.51.57.214.1028     10.51.57.181.55438    ESTABLISHED
```

I'm only interested in the foreign addresses, as the local address changes per server.
They're either actually established, or treated as stale sockets and the switch has orphaned them (which is generally the cause of multiple established sockets)

It looks like the only way to find these is to look for a tab, then dotted quad, followed by a socket number, then a tab then ESTABLISHED.  The logged comes from an ancient version of vxworks, so the socket number isn't prefixed by a colon, but we can assume all endpoints are larger than 1024

I can't logically work out the best way to display a filtered set of the IP addresses, then sort them by number of connections?  I'd like to see which appear have more than two concurrent connections

I think I'm okay with leaving the local address in there, as having 250-odd connections would logically be the local address!

Many thanks

Comment: Hi Jeff - I had accepted it, but clearly something went wrong!  Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an `awk` script to search for the IP's in the data; collect each occurrence of them in a `counts` array. When the input has all been read, loop through the array and print the counts and the IP's, but only if there's been more than two occurrences, then pipe it all to sort:

## awkscript:

```
NF == 7 && $7 == "ESTABLISHED" {
  split($6, octets, ".")
  ip=octets[1] "." octets[2] "." octets[3] "." octets[4]
  counts[ip]++
}

END {
  for (i in counts)
    if (counts[i] > 2)
        print counts[i], i
}
```

Run it like:

```
awk -f awkscript < input | sort -n
```

With the sample input, only one IP comes out, with 5 occurrences:

```
5 10.51.57.203
```

Comment: Thanks Jeff!  I've always been a bit scared by awk!  
I've found that for some reason in the original source it doesn't find established, so changed the first condition to not match 'LISTEN' which seems to work a treat!  

Thank you very much - that solves me a log of aggravation!